# The volume of the cube whose two faces lie on the plane $6x-3y+2z+1=0 $ and $6x-3y+2z+4=0$

Tags: calculus, geometry, proof-verification, analytic-geometry

The volume of the cube whose two faces lie on the plane $6x-3y+2z+1=0 $  and $6x-3y+2z+4=0$ is equal to

(a) 27

(b) 27/349

(c) 3/7

(D) 10

My work : the distance between the two plane is$ =\frac{6-3+2+4}{\sqrt{6^2+3^2+2^2}}-\frac{6-3+2+1}{\sqrt{6^2+3^2+2^2}}=\frac{3}{7}$.

So the length of one side is= 3/7 . Hence volume is $=(\frac{3}{7})^3=\frac{27}{343}$ .

Is my work correct ??

Comment: Looks good to me, except $7^3=343$ .

Comment: Error edited . Thanks .

Comment: What do you mean by "whose two faces ..."?  A cube has six faces.  Did you mean "two of whose faces ..."  The two planes are, of course parallel with normal vector <6, 3, 2>.  (-1, 1, -1) satisfies 2(

Comment: That is a really good question : Unfortunately the question posted is exactly the same from the book i copied it . The question no extra info other than the mentioned ones . So i guess the author of the question meant opposite faces ,